# configure fail : C compiler cannot create executable

Tags: configure

I was using ./configure on my project when I got this error:

checking for powerpc-gcc... ppc_60x-gcc

checking for C compiler default output file name...

configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables

See `config.log' for more details.

Here is the error :

cc1: error: invalid option `arch=c674x'

cc1: error: invalid option `arch=c674x'

configure:2068: $? = 1

configure: failed program was:

| /* confdefs.h.  */